# How to keep sequelize associations name in lower_case?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, naming-conventions

Cannot get my foreignKey in lower_case, all my associations are PascalCase.

So I have a simple table "user" with role_id (foreignKey)
And I have table "role".
So when create a user it works fine. But when I query it search for foreignKey name like RoleId instead of role_id.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    tableName: "role"
  });
  Role.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Role.hasMany(models.User)
  };
  return Role;
}
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: false,
    },
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    role_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    MerchantId: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    tableName: 'user'
  });
  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.Role)
    User.belongsTo(models.Merchant)
  };
  return User;
};
```

Any solution to keep all name lower_case_underscore ?

Comment: If you wish that all foreign keys of all tables will be in the snake case and you use sequelize v4 you can use underscoredAll option. Since v5 this option is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and had to set foreignKey on both sides of the relationship or it would automatically use `RoleId`.

```
Role.hasMany(models.User, {foreignKey: 'role_id'});
...
User.belongsTo(models.Role, {foreignKey: 'role_id'});
```

Another option is to set `underscored: true` in the global config. You would keep all your attribute names in camel case but the table names and field names would be in snake case.

```
  config = {
    "development": {
       ...
       "define": {
          "underscored": true
       }
    }
  }

  const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
User.belongsTo(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'role_id' ))
```

Comment: I had to rename all my model in camelCase to get rid of pascalcase.